# What property of natural exponential 'e' would be used to simplify and solve this limit?

Tags: limits

The limit is:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac {2-2e^{-x}}{e^x-1}$$

I managed to simply the limit to:
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac {-2(e^{-x}-1)}{e^x-1}$$

But I am wondering how I would remove the $-x$ from the $e$ in the numerator? Is there some property that I should be using?
Intuitively I know the answer would be $2$, but I want to know the steps to get there. Thanks.

Comment: use lim(e^X-1)/X=1

Comment: In other words, if you factor $e^{-x}$ out of the numerator you get $-2(e^{-x})\frac{1- e^x}{e^x-1}= 2e^{-x}$ as long as x is not 0.  Now you can also use the property that $e^x$ is "continuous" for all x.  In particular, that means $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-x}= e^0= 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac {-2(e^{-x}-1)}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac {-2(\frac{1}{e^x}-1)}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac {-2(1-e^{x})}{e^x(e^x-1)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac {2(e^{x}-1)}{e^x(e^x-1)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac {2}{e^x}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* it simplifies to
$$\frac {2\mathrm e^{-x}(\mathrm e^x-1)}{e^x-1}=2\mathrm e^{-x}.$$

Comment: All too easy.  +1 for this concise and complete "hint"

Comment: @Dr. MV: It's not complete. I didn't add $\mathrm e^{-x}$ is continuous… ;o)

Comment: That was funny. :-))

Answer (score 0):

Why? Just use Hôpital. Applying the rule you get:

$$\frac{2e^{-x}}{e^x}$$

Which gives you $\boxed{2}$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Continuity of the exponential function is enough.

Answer (score 0):

we have
$f(x)=\frac{2(e^{-x}-1)}{-x} \frac{x}{e^{x}-1}$

$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=2$